# Using webdriver execute-script on jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium, webdriver

I was trying to use webdriver's execute_script() to run a jquery, but without luck. Below are the steps I performed:

1. From Selenium/Webdriver, run execute_script() as below:

   ```
   jquery_string = 'return $(\'[id="ClusterMembers:ClusterMembersScreen:ttlBar"]\')'    
   web_element = driver.execute_script(jquery_string)
   ```

   It returned error as:

   > WebDriverException: Message: $ is not defined
   >
   > Build info: version: '2.53.0'
   >        ...
2. Hold the above function call from debugger, 
   go to the standing FF browser from the selenium client machine,
   and type in the same jquery string from the Developer Console as below (after typing "allow pasting"):

   ```
   $('[id="ClusterMembers:ClusterMembersScreen:ttlBar"]')
   ```

   => The console returns as expected
3. Added the following codes before running the same above code as (1):

   ```
   driver.execute_script(open('Cjquery-2.2.4.js').read())
   TestCase.assertTrue(cluster_page.driver_util.driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"))
   ```

   => Returned value of "web_element" from the debugger is not a webelement object, but a **dictionary** of the following:

   ```
   {'mouseout': 'function ( data, fn ) {\n\t\treturn arguments.length > 0 ?\n\t\t\tthis.on( name, null, data, fn ) :\n\t\t\tthis.trigger( name );\n\t}', ....
   ```

   I have tried to use a latest version of jquery (3.1), but still got the same failure.

I was wondering if the issue has something to do with the **"allow pasting"** required by the FF or something else that I have been missing? I appreciate if anyone can shed some light?

Comment: I see that your script script is actually a jquery selector. Why not use the regular methods for finding the selector from selenium? also using double quote outside could help in adding extra escape for the inside single quotes.

Comment: Yes, I was using jquery, and this post is meant for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $ try using this:

```
jquery_string = "jQuery('[id*=ClusterMembers][id*=ClusterMembersScreen][id*=ttlBar]');"
```

try to avoid using ':' in selectors, it might result in errors.